# How to install PyTorch natively on Apple M1 with Miniforge?

Tags: apple-m1, mini-forge

I'd like to run PyTorch natively on my M1 MacBook Air. I followed [these instructions](https://towardsdatascience.com/yes-you-can-run-pytorch-natively-on-m1-macbooks-and-heres-how-35d2eaa07a83) which say to start with

```
brew install miniforge
```

`brew info miniforge` confirms that I installed the `osx-arm64` version, so that's fine. Then I did

```
conda create --name pytorch_env python=3.8
```

This should download and install a few packages, but when they are listed before installation I see that they are all `osx-64`, not `osx-arm64`. The same happens for the actual PyTorch installation:

```
conda install -c pytorch pytorch
```

Only `osx-64` packages get installed. I completed the process and ran a sample script which confirmed that I only have the Intel version running.

I then installed universal Python 3.9.6 and tried to create an environment with Python 3.9, but this did not make a difference.

I also have an Anaconda3 installation on this machine, which is probably x86-only (the installer is).

What can I do now?

Comment: the instructions are behind a paywall

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It was the leftover from my Anaconda3 installation, indeed.

I had to delete the `conda initialize` part in my `.zshrc` file. Then I reran the instructions starting from `conda init zsh`, and it worked.